# VC++ 2015 doesn't link but VC++ 2012 did

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, stl

I'm experiencing a strange error while moving our projects from VS2012 update 4 to VS2015 update 3. In the solution, half of the projects compile using VC++ (MSVC 14.0) and half of the projects compile using Intel C++ 13.0.

***Everything compiles correctly.***

The problem occurs when it's time to link. I get errors like this one that seems to be in the `std` files...

```
Error   LNK2019 

unresolved external symbol 

"public: virtual void __cdecl std::basic_istream<wchar_t,struct
std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::_Add_vtordisp1(void)"
(?_Add_vtordisp1@?$basic_istream@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@std@@UEAAXXZ) 

referenced in function 

"[thunk]:public: virtual void __cdecl std::basic_istream<wchar_t,struct
std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::_Add_vtordisp1`vtordisp{4294967292,128}'
(void)" (?_Add_vtordisp1@?$basic_istream@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@std@@$4PPPPPPPM@IA@EAAXXZ)
```

I can neither reproduce the bug with a spike solution nor give you a piece of code where the bug occurs because it seems to be in `std`.

When I look in file `istream`, I find something like `#pragma vtordisp(push,2) //compiler bug workaroung` but I cannot figure what bug it is or how to fix it.

Any clue/hint would be appreciate.

Thank you!

Comment: So take the project.  Eliminate half of it.  Does the problem still occur?  Yes?  Repeat until you have something absolutely minimal.  No?  Eliminate a the other half.  This wilk take effort, but should get you at least *somewhere* towarsa a [mcve]

Comment: @Yakk I just wanted to know if someone faced the same problem. Of course, I'll have to use the dichotomy method...

Comment: Are you linking modules compiled with different versions of MSVC by any chance?

Comment: @dxiv No. I rebuilt from a clean workspace. I suspect I miss a link to Intel libraries since I did not reinstall ICC but I kept the old installation. The error occurs when a C++/CLI compiled with MSVC tries to link to a .lib compiled with ICC. I guess I will have to reinstall ICC to make sure all the setup with VS2015 is correct.

Comment: I don't see VC++ 2015 listed as an option for [`/Qvc`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/513301) even for Intel C++ 14, so it may not be available for v13 either.

Comment: Yep... Maybe my problem is there. Does someone know if one can link ICC 13.0 lib with VS2015/MSVC 14 dll/assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

Install Windows 10 SDK and and then re target your solution to use this latest SDK. Also make sure you code should be properly migrated to VS 2015 and dependencies are you using with your project should be of VS 2015 other wise it would give another error.